# All records modified when updating EFsms data, instead of just the selected records

Tags: sms, apdu

I'm trying to update the EFsms as described in the [3GPP specifications](http://www.3gpp.org/specifications) ([TS 102 221 file](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102200_102299/102221/08.02.00_60/ts_102221v080200p.pdf)), and I get some unexpected behavior.

I'm using the following commands to update the EF :

- SELECT EFsms (under ADF) - `00 A4 00 00 02 6F 3C`
- UPDATE RECORD - `00 DC 00 00 B0` [TPDU]

Here is an example of a TPDU I used (I masked the addresses):

```
030791XXXXXXXXXXFX640C91XXXXXXXXXXXX001271208181015180
```

(with trailing FF so its length is 176 bytes)

Then I'm trying to read the records of the file, using :

- SELECT EFsms (under ADF) - `00 A4 00 00 02 6F 3C`
- READ RECORD - `00 B2 XX 00 B0` (where XX is the record number 0x01-0x0A)

When I read back the record, *every* record has the updated values, even if I did not first select it. This happens whether or not I specify the exact record to update.

How can I update just the selected records?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the APDUs for updating and reading were wrong.

It should be :

- UPDATE RECORD - 00 DC **XX 04** B0 [TPDU]
- READ RECORD - 00 B2 **XX 04** B0

Where XX is the record number.
Because I used P2=0, it used the CURRENT RECORD mode for the updating and reading instead of the ABSOLUTE mode.